# Blank screen after creating invoice and redirect issues

Tags: onepage-checkout, invoice

I'm Having 2 issues in my magento 1.9.1 app.

When I'm trying to proceed one page checkout my page redirects me to cart (but I can see in magento admin that order is placed with success)

Second issue is , when I'm tring to create invoice with comment and send it to customer i got blank page and invoice is not created. 
I can create invoice without sending e-mail without any error.

My system log shows:
1 Checkout issue

```
    2015-06-21T10:43:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback  in /lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 269
2015-06-21T10:43:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback  in /lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 269
```

1. Invoice Issue - error is the same , so I suspect that problem is with `Emogrifier.php` file. I found that problem could be not enabled mbstring extension is php. In my Php mbstring is enabled.

I'm having magento 1.9.1 installation with PHP Version 5.4.23

emogifier function

```
public function emogrify() {
    if ($this->html === '') {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Please set some HTML first before calling emogrify.', 1390393096);
    }

    $xmlDocument = $this->createXmlDocument();
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($xmlDocument);
    $this->clearAllCaches();

    // before be begin processing the CSS file, parse the document and normalize all existing CSS attributes (changes 'DISPLAY: none' to 'display: none');
    // we wouldn't have to do this if DOMXPath supported XPath 2.0.
    // also store a reference of nodes with existing inline styles so we don't overwrite them
    $this->purgeVisitedNodes();

    $nodesWithStyleAttributes = $xpath->query('//*[@style]');
    if ($nodesWithStyleAttributes !== FALSE) {
        /** @var $nodeWithStyleAttribute \DOMNode */
        foreach ($nodesWithStyleAttributes as $node) {
            $normalizedOriginalStyle = preg_replace_callback(
                '/[A-z\\-]+(?=\\:)/S',
                function (array $m) {
                    return strtolower($m[0]);
                },
                //269 line below
                $node->getAttribute('style')
            );

            // in order to not overwrite existing style attributes in the HTML, we have to save the original HTML styles
            $nodePath = $node->getNodePath();
            if (!isset($this->styleAttributesForNodes[$nodePath])) {
                $this->styleAttributesForNodes[$nodePath] = $this->parseCssDeclarationBlock($normalizedOriginalStyle);
                $this->visitedNodes[$nodePath] = $node;
            }

            $node->setAttribute('style', $normalizedOriginalStyle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Blank page is php error issue, check 'exception.log' or HTTP server logs for errors

Answer (score 0):

Comment the following out:

```
$normalizedOriginalStyle = preg_replace_callback(
    '/[A-z\\-]+(?=\\:)/S',
    function (array $m) {
        return strtolower($m[0]);
    },
    //269 line below
    $node->getAttribute('style')
);
```

Place under the following:

```
$normalizedOriginalStyle = strtolower($node->getAttribute('style'));
```

This will accomplish most of what the function should be doing.